# Is it possible to re-size a div on window re-size without using JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

I need to set the size of a div, in my case  `#panel-container`, when the viewport reach the size of 450px in height.

Basically the `#panel-container` should shrink as the user make smaller the browser window leaving the div always visible within the viewport.

I would like to know if possible to achieve this effect without using JS and only using CSS.
I am aware of CSS media queries but I need the re-sizing happening while user re-size the window.

I can use latest browsers and HTML5 and CSS3 features.
Any ideas is welcome.

http://jsbin.com/jefibidizo/1/

```js
window.app = {
  start: function() {}
};
```

```css
 body {
   background-color: darkslateblue;
 }
 #header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: dimgray;
 }
 #panel-wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50px;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: moccasin;
 }
 #panel-container {
   width: 200px;
   height: 400px;
   overflow: auto;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Builder</title>

</head>

<body onload="app.start();">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="panel">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div id="panel-wrapper">
      <div id="panel-container">
        <div id="panel-content">
          some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long
          text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long
          text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long
          text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long
          text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long
          text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long
          text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long
          text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long
          text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long
          text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long
          text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here. some long text here, some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long text here,some long
          text here,some long text here,some long text here.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with media querys - [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/medipoxabi/1/)?

Comment: use css3 @media Rule ?

Comment: @Vucko thanks for your hit, but I need to change the height of the div, look at this edit, i am not able to make it with media queries ... http://jsbin.com/hejiwaqoge/1/

Comment: @GibboK that's because you're using `fixed` for your all elements. You have to use reduce 50px (which is the header height) from 100% height - [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hawocelezo/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I need also to use calc like this correct? http://jsbin.com/libajayuvo/1/edit

Comment: @GibboK yes, if you want a pure CSS solution, you can use [calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `calc` to set the height of the `div` to 100% of the viewport height, less the height of your header and then setting its `max-height` to `400px` (or whatever you need it to be).

- [More information on `calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)
- [Browser support for `calc`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)
- [More information on viewport percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)
- [Browser support for viewport percentage lengths](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)
- [More information on `max-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height)

Here's a quick example for you:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
html{height:100%;}
body{height:200%;margin:0;}
div{
    background:#ccc;
    height:calc(100vh - 50px);
    max-height:300px;
    font-family:arial;
    left:0;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:5px;
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    width:25%;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras leo erat, blandit ac est nec, congue fermentum dui. Duis vitae urna enim. Cras vulputate ante at ante dictum porta. Cras placerat dolor augue, in eleifend lectus fermentum scelerisque. Aenean dui magna, pharetra eu est sed, volutpat molestie libero. Sed dictum pellentesque tellus, ac rhoncus turpis dictum eu. Sed id aliquet ex. Suspendisse scelerisque sem odio, sit amet pharetra elit viverra at. Ut gravida congue rutrum. Proin at velit laoreet, venenatis mauris vitae, condimentum lectus. Ut mollis purus eu dolor finibus tincidunt.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well, here I have applied your suggestions in my code, works great! http://jsbin.com/tefufuluda/1/

Comment: Just adding an interesting article about viewport percentage lenghts http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/7-css-units-you-might-not-know-about--cms-22573

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 media queries for this. [Check out this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Something like:

`@media (max-width: 600px) {
    div#YOUR_DIV {
        width: 100px;
    }
}`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am afraid it does not work as expected, I am not able to set the height dynamically accordingly the viewport, here an example: http://jsbin.com/quwimapani/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Soluition 1:

Use width of the div in percentages , like 80%. By this according to window width the width of the div will reduce or increage according to browser width

Solutions 2:

use media queries if above option fails

```
@media (max-width : 900px) and (min-width: 500px)
{
  div{
       width:200px;
    }
}

 @media (max-width : 400px) and (min-width: 500px)
{
  div{
       width:100px;
    }
}
```

use @media in ccs , @@media in html page

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure how ideal this solution is but it does ahiceve the effect you want

```
#panel-wrapper {
            position: fixed;
            width: -moz-calc(100% - 80%);
            width: -webkit-calc(100% - 80%);
            width: -o-calc(100% - 80%);
            width: calc(100% - 80%);
            z-index: 10;
            padding-right: 80%;
            top: 50px;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #panel-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
            overflow: auto;
            background-color: moccasin;
        }
```

Above is what I amended from your code

Comment: Sorry this covers width not height. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this only in one line 
Use **vw in place of px** and everything will be as responsive as images

read this to understand

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/